# Exchange EWS Folder Syncing only picking up programmatic changes

Tags: c#, exchange-server, synchronization, exchangewebservices

Using this code I'm creating a proof of concept for syncing My Exchange (2007 SP1) driven outlook calendar syncable to other calendaring systems via the **[Exchange EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)**.

```
    static void SyncAppointments()
    {
        ChangeCollection<ItemChange> changeCollection = service.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar), PropertySet.FirstClassProperties, null, 512, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, syncState);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Changes");
        Console.WriteLine("============================\n");

        if (changeCollection.Count > 0) {
            foreach (ItemChange item in changeCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ChangeType: " + item.ChangeType.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ItemId: " + item.ItemId.UniqueId);
                Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + item.Item.Subject);
                Console.WriteLine("===========\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("No changes to Sync.\n");
        }

        syncState = changeCollection.SyncState;
    }
```

This is working great for the **most part**, I get the default first set of changes (all items) and subsequently I get `No changes to Sync.`... now when I create an appointment via the EWS and then run the sync operation **I get the expected result**. A change item reflecting the creation of the appointment (and it appearing in outlook) appears.

```
Changes
============================

ChangeType: Create
ItemId: AAMkADRjYjE1NTVlLTk5ODktNGJiYS1hMTdjLTU2MzE5OGU5ZWNlOABGAAAAAADPxihYdsIG
TqRV5hKVbnQhBwASbprVW92zQZkfrIZIxiR2AEg2AOQDAAASbprVW92zQZkfrIZIxiR2AEg2KWYFAAA=

Subject: New Appointment
===========
```

Now if I add/cancel appointments **via outlook the syncing operation does not pick up the changes**.

```
Changes
============================

No changes to Sync.
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking `MoreChangesAvailable`? You could be losing them between calls if you have many changes (greater than `maxChangesReturned`).

You should write out the syncState to see what it contains. Make sure it is getting passed properly - it is essentially a hash of the last sync datetime.